# Is it possible to Access the Data of an non opend file and modify it with the vscode API

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on an VS Code rename extension for `Angular` components and for that I need to change the data in the typescript file as well as in the `spec.ts` file. To edit the typescript file I'm able to use the `vscode.windiow.activeTextEditor`, but I don't know how I can get access to the `spec.ts` file via the API.

I tried to change the `activeEditor` by showing the other document but it seems to not change the `activeEditor` directly (When I debug the `activeEditor` doesn't change).

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right then you just want to open an arbitrary file, change it and save it, in your extension, correct?

If that's the case then simply use the `fs` ([file system](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html)) node module to load and save the file.